# Why topology indicates edge state?

Tags: condensed-matter, topological-field-theory, spin-models

I have learned some models with topology like Kitaev chain and SSH. All of them possess edge states if the bulk is topologically non-trivial. The reading materials did the calculation and verified this point. But there is no exact proof or even illustrations of why this (so-called bulk-edge correspondence) would happen since with some basic knowledge of quantum mechanics, I can always make some bound state in edge artificially.

Comment: Which reading material? Which page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rough idea is that a topological medium has a gap in its spectrum that is in some sense qualitatively different from the one in vacuum (or some other ``trivial'' gapped material like, say, GaAs crystal). Therefore one cannot smoothly evolve one gap type into another. This means that the gap must close somewhere near the interface. Hence the edge/surface state(s).

Comment: Thanks for answering! But I still have some problems with this picture.  Your picture is based on the fact that the electron can move freely through the edge so that the comparison of topology (inside the sample or outside the sample) makes sense, which is not the case in the vacuum.      Also, why must we evolve one gap type into another?  There is a  discontinuity in this situation (two systems connected)

Comment: Well, vacuum is also a "trivial insulator" in the sense that the gap $\Delta =2m c^2$ in it can be smoothly ("adiabatically") tuned to some smaller values. This does not lead to any phase transitions or any other catastrophies, hence is a valid topological procedure. Likewise you can tune the work function down. The thing about TI's is that their gapped ground state is not tunable ("adiabatically connected") this way to a trivial insulator, while a vacuum is.

Comment: OK, thanks very much!